# backbone error:"Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) users"

Tags: backbone.js

Im trying to create a simple application using backbone..

When i am trying to run my code,this error shows

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404
>   (Not Found)      users.

What this program really does is, just call the `router.js` file and render a simple html..

Please help me to clear the error..

If i use `ajax prefilter` then no errors and also no output.

Im using eclipse and tomcat server7. 
 And also my important question is

> How to use a RESTful Api in a Backbone program and give me a sample
>   program?

Here is my code..

My HTML code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Welcome Backbone</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h1>User Manager</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="page"></div>
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js" 
        type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.4.2/underscore-min.js" 
        type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/0.9.2/backbone-min.js" 
        type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/router.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

My js code:

```
/**
 * New node file
 */
/* $.ajaxPrefilter(function(options, originalOptions, jqXHR) {
                 options.url='http://localhost:8080/PageProject/#'+options.url;
                 console.log(options.url);
             }); */
var Users = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    url: '/users'
});
var UserList = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '.page',
    render: function () {
        var that = this;
        var users1 = new Users();
        users1.fetch({
            success: function () {
                that.$el.html('!CONTENT SHOULD BE HERE');
                console.log('request reached');
            }
        });
    }
});
var Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes: {
        '': 'home'
    }
});

var UserList = new UserList();
var router = new Router();
router.on('route:home', function () {
    console.log('Welcome Backbone!');
    UserList.render();
});

Backbone.history.start();
```

Comment: Backbone's collection.fetch method attempts to sync your collection with the server: http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-fetch

What does your server return for the /users endpoint? If there isn't anything at /users you will get a 404.

Comment: On the browser in which you're viewing your website, use something to see what requests are being made of your server.  For example in Firefox, have the tool at Tools, Web Developer, Network open when you run your javascript.  It will show you the request of the server.  Then figure out what how your server is set up to handle the request.